# The parameter '' was not bound in the specified LINQ to Entities query expression

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda

I saw that there are many questions with similar title but none of them solved my problem.
I'm generating this lambda expression using a long and complex code which I don't want to paste here (I can paste if necessary) :

```
{Param_0 => (((Param_0.AD == "JASON") And (Param_1.AD == "JASON")) And (Param_2.STATE== "GEORGIA"))}
```

And I'm using this expression like this :

```
            var cust= db.CUST.Where(lambdaExpression);

            var custList= cust.ToList();
```

When it comes to ToList(), it gives this error :

> The parameter '' was not bound in the specified LINQ to Entities query
>   expression.

What is wrong with my lambda expression? When I try something else, it works, but it doesn't work with this one. Thanks.

EDIT :

Here is my code :

```
 var property = typeof(CUSTOMER).GetProperty(newArray[0], BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);

                var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(CUSTOMER));

                var memberExpression = Expression.Property(parameter, property);

                var value = Convert.ChangeType(newArray[1], property.PropertyType, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

                var eq = Expression.Equal(memberExpression, Expression.Constant(value));

                if (/*some condition*/)
                {



                    foreach (var elem in someotherlist)
                    {
                        var newelem= elem.Replace(" ", string.Empty);

                        string[] newArray = newelem.Split(':');
                        var listproperty = typeof(CUSTOMER).GetProperty(newArray[0], BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);

                        var listparameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(CUSTOMER));

                        var listmemberExpression = Expression.Property(listparameter, listproperty);

                        var listvalue = Convert.ChangeType(newArray[1], property.PropertyType, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

                        var eqnew = Expression.Equal(listmemberExpression, Expression.Constant(listvalue));

                        eq = Expression.And(eq, eqnew); // I guess problem is here.
                    }


                }
```

Comment: You need to give us the actual code you're using. This doesn't give us any clue as to what parameter wasn't bound.

Comment: @krillgar It could be `STATE`, because it works without `STATE`.

Comment: How are we supposed to know that?

Comment: In your pseudo code you have just one parameter (Param0) but reference two more in expression itself (Param_1 and Param_2). Just post some real code indeed.

Comment: Both `Param_1` and `Param_2` are wrong - the lambda should have only one parameter `Param_0` (note `Param_0 => ...`). Most likely you are combining incorrectly lambda expressions.

Comment: @Evk I posted the code.

Comment: You declare `listparameter` several times (inside a foreach), I doubt that was intended. You need to move it outside foreach.

Comment: @Evk I moved that out. Now I get this : `{Param_0 => (((Param_0.AD == "JASON") And (Param_1.AD == "JASON")) And (Param_1.STATE== "GEORGIA"))}`

Comment: Well that means you still have another wrong parameter somewhere. Maybe it's in code you provided, maybe not, because you did not provide a full code and code you did provide cannot be copy-pasted and executed so we are still left guessing.

Comment: @Evk I provided all the code that generates the lambda expresssion. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Remove `var listparameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(CUSTOMER));` and use `parameter` variable instead.